# Node JS | Can't use variable in multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I try to use a variable declared inside an function in a other file too.
Here's where I'm declaring the variable:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    var GuildId = message.guild.id;
});
```

And I want to use "GuildId" in an other file too.
I tried exporting it:

```
module.exports = {
        GuildId
    }
```

And then importing it:

```
const { GuildId } =require("../main.js")
```

But in the file I'm importing it the variable is undefined... I have absolutely no Idea why it is like that...

Oh yeah.. I also tried exporting it with:

```
exports.GuildId = message.guild.id;
```

And:

```
GuildID = message.guild.id;
```

But it also didn't work. Any Ideas? :c

**EDIT:**

It's a Discord Bot that as a MemberCount function so it makes a Channel that shows how many Users are on the Discord. So I want to use the GuildId to get this customizable Channel ID from my MYSQL Databse. For that I need to have the GuildID. I do that with:

```
connection.promise().query( GuildId,
        `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${GuidId}'`
    ).then(result => {
        MemberCountChannel.set(GuidId, result[0][0].memberCountId);
        MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(GuidId);
```

I cant't get the Guild Id using "guild.id" 'cause I'm to stupid and it doesn't work. What I mean by that:

```
 connection.promise().query( GuildId,
        `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${guild.id}'`
    ).then(result => {
        MemberCountChannel.set(guild.id, result[0][0].memberCountId);
        MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(guild.id);
```

EDIT 2:

Here is my full member-counter.js:

const { connection } = require("../database/db");

```
module.exports = async (client) =>{
    
    setInterval(() => {
        
    let ts = Date.now();
    let date_ob = new Date(ts);
    let date = date_ob.getDate();
    let month = (date_ob.getMonth()+1);
    let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
    let hours = ('0' + (date_ob.getHours()+1)).slice(-2);
    let minutes = ('0' + (date_ob.getMinutes()+1)).slice(-2);
    let seconds = ('0' + (date_ob.getSeconds()+1)).slice(-2);

    const { globals } = require("../main.js");
    
    const GuildId = globals.GuildId;

        console.log('GuildId: ' + GuidId);

    let MemberCountChannel = new Map();
    module.exports.getMemberCount = (guildId) => {

    connection.promise().query( GuildId,
        `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${GuidId}'`
    ).then(result => {
        MemberCountChannel.set(GuidId, result[0][0].memberCountId);
        MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(GuidId);

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GuidId);
        const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(MemberCountChannelId);
        console.log(MemberCountChannelId)
        channel.setName(`Mitglieder: ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('[INFO] '.green + year + '/' + month + '/' + date + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' Updating Member Count...');
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    };
    }, 15000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the message is asynchronous, you can't use it elsewhere synchronously. I think here, instead of the other file importing the GuildId, have your *main* file import the member count file as a function, so you can retrieve the member count when needed when a message comes:

```
// getMemberCount.js
module.exports.getMemberCount = (guildId) => {
  return connection.promise().query( GuildId,
        `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${GuidId}'`
    ).then(result => {
        MemberCountChannel.set(GuidId, result[0][0].memberCountId);
        MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(GuidId);
        // do other stuff with MemberCountChannelId
   });
};
```

```
// main.js
const { getMemberCount } = require('./getMemberCount');
client.on('message', (message) => {
    getMemberCount(message.guild.id)
     .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this, don't want unhandled rejections
});
```

Comment: Well no... Now it's executing the Member Count every time someone writs a message... But that's not what I want... I'm currently calling the Member Count when the bot is ready and then using "setInterval(() => {..." to repeat it every 15 min...

Comment: *I'm currently calling the Member Count when the bot is ready* Sure, if that's the logic you want, feel free to do that instead. Is that working for you? Or did you want something different?

Comment: It actually somehow says: 
"getMemberCount(message.guild.id).catch(handleErrors); Type Error: getMemberCount is not a function"

Comment: It sounds like you're not importing the function properly. Make sure you do `module.exports.getMemberCount = (guildId) => {` and that your import path is correct

Comment: I did everything like you said... I now put in my full file for you to see... Could it be a problem that i already got "module.exports = async (client) => {..." and is that actually necessary?

Comment: You used a different way of exporting than in my answer. I used `module.exports.getMemberCount`, you used `module.exports = async (client) =>{`. If you assign to `module.exports`, the import should not be destructured, since the import is the function itself, not an object that holds the function. Use `const getMemberCount = require('./getMemberCount');`

Comment: Yeah, I realised that too... :D Was a little stupid there... :D Now it's working just fine! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are already implementing the correct solution to share variables across modules. However, the problem is your variable is storing a value - in this case I presume a string or number. In which case each module will get a copy of the value.

What you need is to export a pointer/reference. In order to do that you need to export an object or array. The best solution in this case is to export an object:

Another problem is you are declaring (var) the variable you want inside the callback. This makes in inaccessible to code outside the scope of the callback. You need to declare it in a shared scope with your `module.exports`

```
var globals = {}

client.on('message', (message) => {
    globals.GuildId = message.guild.id;
});

module.exports.globals = globals;
```

Now you can import it:

```
const { globals } =require("../main.js");
const GuildId = globals.GuildId;
```

Comment: When doing it exactly like you wrote it I get the following error:

/home/ubuntu/discord-bot-v2/counters/member-counter.js:18
    const GuildId = globals.GuildId;
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'GuildId' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/discord-bot-v2/counters/member-counter.js:18:29)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)

Comment: It appears you have not defined `globals` as an object. You need to do `var globals = {}`

Comment: Do note that this answer is mainly applicable to the original question of sharing variables. This design pattern does not solve issues of timing due to asynchronous code which was not included in the original question